# trying to determine if an app uses web api 2 or something else?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I'm reviewing an app and I think it's Web API 2 but there's a packages.config reference to:

```
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi" version="5.2.4" targetFramework="net461" />
```

So does this config entry show that the app is "Web API 2" or something else? Also is Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi the standard/only package name for "Web API 2"? Does "Web API 2" not have a version number of 2.#.# but rather 5.2.4?

Answer (score 0):

"Web API 2" is basically an upgrade to the original Web API framework.  Version 5.2.4 of the Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi package is indeed "Web API 2".

IIRC, "Web API 2" was introduced with VS 2013 or about at the same time as VS 2013 was released.

There is not direct correlation between the actual version number of the nuget package and "Web API 2". Versions 4.* of the nuget package are "Web API 1" while all versions of 5.* are referenced to as "Web API 2".